# Add setter injection to an existing service

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to add a setter injection to an existing service. The base service is defined as follow:

```
[container] Information for service doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager

Service Id   doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
Class        Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
Tags         -
Scope        container
Public       yes
```

I have overridden the class parameter of the service in the `config.yml` file to use my own class which add a `setExample()` method to the base class. The service definition now looks like:

```
[container] Information for service doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager

Service Id   doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
Class        MyCustom\EntityManager
Tags         -
Scope        container
Public       yes
```

How can I modify/override this service configuration to add my own setter injection in my own `services.yml` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is use the extension class in your bundle DependencyInjection namespace. It should be something like:

```
<?php

namespace YourNamespace\YourBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;

/**
 * Provide a DIC extension to support configurable cheeta subscription adapters.
 */
class YourNamespaceYourBundleExtension extends Extension 
{    
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load( array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container )
    {
        // Some stuff with configuration...
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration( $configuration, $configs );
        // Load service configuration
        $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader( $container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config' ) );
        $loader->load( 'services.xml' );
        $container->findDefinition('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager')->addMethodCall('setExample', array(/* Eventual parameters */));
    }

}
```

There is probably also a way to do the same using service inheritance, but I never tried. In the Extension class however you can do the same things you do in the service.xml file plus use php logic and semantic configuration to do more advanced stuffs.